# How do I make sure my profiling stats are accurate/consistent on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, caching, profiling

When I'm profiling a python script for example.  Lets say I opened 1000 images, read some of the header data, and then printed that data to the screen.

How can I sure that next time I run this script that nothing has been cached, or being kept in ram etc, and it is being run as if its the first time again?

I'm using Centos and I've seen commands to flush the cache like:

```
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
```

But this has to be run as root which I'm trying to avoid, and is this enough to make sure that I'll get accurate stats next time I run the script?

Edit - Also if this is a plugin for another program, would you have to close that program every time to get accurate results?

Comment: Load a bunch of random other files in the interim? That's kind of a brutish soln.

Comment: Do you mean for those random files to take the place of whatever was cached by the script?  If so wouldn't that be also kind of time consuming and still not be accurate?

Comment: You load those files when you are NOT measuring the time... ;)

Comment: My opinion on this is that trying to remove all variable factors from the system is going to be difficult if not impossible. Maybe you need to back up a bit and explain what it is you are trying to achieve. Getting "accurate stats" is a means not an ends. So what is your ends? Depending on that, the degree of "accurate stats" required may change and make your problem easier to solve.

Comment: The example above is pretty much what i was profiling, i had to read between 400-2000 images to extract some data from the headers of each, but I wasn't sure how to make sure that each and everytime i run the script that nothing was cached/getting reused etc

Comment: The question isn't what are you profiling. The question is what are you trying to achieve with the profiling? For example, your program is taking 2 minutes and you want to reduce that down to at least under 30 seconds. For such an example, you probably don't need to try and remove all caching and other variable effects to achieve that. In other words, why do you think you need super accurate and repeatable profiling stats? What is it that you are trying to achieve that requires that?

Comment: maybe accurate was the wrong word, i think consistency is more what i was after, that's why i mentioned caching, because if all of those images were cached, it would run much faster.  then if in between tests, something flushed part of the cache or overwrite it, then i would get a different speed result again.

Comment: Sorry to hammer the point. But the question is still the same. What is your end goal? Why do you need the stats to be consistent? I guess having consistent stats is a valid goal in itself (though there usually is a purpose behind doing such things). So if that is your end goal then just say so. On the other hand if, for example, you are trying to find performance issues with your application then some variability in stats might still be adequate to achieve that goal. Hence the repeated questions - why are you profiling and what do you hope to achieve with the profiled data?